# Count specific elements and add count to class name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classname

How can I count the number of elements with a specific class and add the count to each one as a new class name with jquery?

```
$('.full-screen').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('.full-screen-', i);
});
```

I want to create:

```
<div class="full-screen full-screen-1"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-2"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-3"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-4"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-5"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
$('.full-screen').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('full-screen-'+(i+1));

});
```

---

```js
$('.full-screen').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass('full-screen-'+(i+1));
    console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-1"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-2"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-3"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-4"></div>
<div class="full-screen full-screen-5"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think we need a `.` inside the addClass

Comment: @Abhi You are right. We don't need. Copy paster from OP code and haven't noticed it. However add class removing it :)

Comment: @Mohammad Why should I ?? Even I do, I comment.

Comment: Anyway in demo, you have `full-screen-1~5` but trying to add them.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use [`.addClass( function )`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead of using `.each()`

```
$('.full-screen').addClass(function(i) {
    return 'full-screen-'+(i+1);
});
```

```js
$('.full-screen').addClass(function(i) {
    return 'full-screen-'+(i+1);
});
console.log($('.full-screen'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-screen"></div>
<div class="full-screen"></div>
<div class="full-screen"></div>
<div class="full-screen"></div>
<div class="full-screen"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".full-screen").each(function((i){
    $(this).addClass("full-screen-" + (i+1));
});
```

Comment: Way to copy and paste an answer.

Comment: Also, you left the 'i' out of the callback parenthesis.

Comment: I take time on write answer so that you not down the vote anyone